# Direct deposit in UK in USD or wire transfer from USA: What would be the best option?

Tags: foreign-exchange, wire-transfer

A conference where I am invited to, as a speaker, asks to select either one of the following 2 options for money transfer:

1. Direct deposit in USD
2. Wire transfer.
   The conference is happening in London UK. But, if selected the wire transfer, they shall be wiring from the USA.

So, **which option would be beneficial for me (Indian citizen), considering the commission fee of both?**

---

[Clearning queries from comments]

I am an Indian citizen, who work in India. So, I have an Indian bank account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the direct deposit option would require you to have a US bank account, which you don't have.

So wire transfer is your only option unless you can ask them to try something else, like one of the cheaper money transfer services around. The charges for wire transfers tend to be fairly significant (typically low tens of USD). Depending on your relationship with the payer and the nature of the payment, try to get them to send it with all charges paid so you actually receive the amount you are owed and they cover the charges.